# как работает git ignore

Tags: git

Есть проект. По не опытности, не создал файл git ignore. И все файлы с рабочей папки добавлял в репозиторий. Вопрос: Если его создать сейчас, указать все не нужные файлы, после чего провести все необхоимые процедуры комита и выгрузки, имеющиеся данные в репозитории приведутся в необходимое состояние?

Comment: начиная с нового коммита да. В старых коммитах файлы все еще будут видны

Comment: новый коммит не внес изменений в репозиторий на git hub..... нашел ответ тут : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил следующим образом:

Это команда удаляет любые измененные файлы из индекса

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

Добавляем и коммитим все файлы

```
git add .
git commit -m ".gitignore is now working"
```

Ну и выгружаем все:

```
git push
```